# Best way to relate PostgreSQL table to layer

Tags: postgis, postgresql, attribute-table, esri-geodatabase, relates

There is an online PostgreSQL database (non-spatial) with water monitoring data which is regularly being updated, in another side is a spatial layer of rivers (for example) which should be represented in ArcGIS Server.

PostgreSQL database is being updated by other users. There is also a web interface to access this data.

I need to relate (not join) layer to this database based on the code (ID) to display respective content (table records) in **ArcGIS Server interface**.

Comment: There are a number of different options, all dependent on how you want to model these relationships. There are several documentation sections on this topic. You'd need to [Edit] the question to provide more details on what you have tried and what isn't working before we can really help.

Comment: Thank you Vince, I have edited my question. And sorry for my English, I really try to improve it:)

Comment: Please show the actual table structure, some example data, and the desired result.